# Responsive Text very huge font asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, text, header, responsive

I used the code for responsive text from this site
[here](http://code.runnable.com/UmkD_Lm4L1gdAAAc/fittext-example-responsive-text)

when i run my page it is responsive but it always displays this very huge font size

i just followed the coding from the website i linked above

Comment: Please be more specific and post HTML/CSS for your code

Comment: Your link is dead, please post more code / informations

Comment: its ok i have fixed the problem fortunately you just need to add some values to the fittext() function when calling it to limit the maximum and minimum font size